# tar + compress folder to tar.gz and removed the folder

Tags: linux, shell-script, tar, compression, gunzip

by the following way we tar the folder presto-server-0.210 to file

```
tar -czvf presto-server-archive.tar.gz presto-server-0.210
```

so after we tar the folder , folder still exists

is it possible to use the tar or other approach and replace the folder to tar file , so folder will removed and instead of folder we create the tar file

Comment: `if tar -czvf presto-server-archive.tar.gz presto-server-0.210; then rm -fr presto-server-0.210; fi`?

Comment: I prefer not use rm -fr , is it possible ?

Comment: @yael Any reason why you prefer not to use `rm -r`?

Comment: the reason is because I need to use the script for all this tasks , and for safety I dont use rm -rf

Comment: If you want to remove a directory and all of its contents, what alternative would you suggest exactly?

Comment: I don't understand, you apparently would be OK with tar removing the directory if there was such an option, but not with using a different command, `rm`, to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the proper way to do this is `rm`. For safety purposes, `tar -jcvf folder.tar folder && rm -rf folder` would *only* execute if the `tar` was successful - see "RETURN VALUE" section of [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).